# Azure - Token is not renewed (Authentication_ExpiredToken). Why?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, adal

I have a C# Azure Web Application that accesses Azure Active Directory to get data from users and groups.

After 1h of activity, I get the following error:

> {"odata.error":{"code":"Authentication_ExpiredToken","message":{"lang":"en","value":"Your access token has expired. Please renew it before submitting the request."},"date":"2018-03-16T16:17:59","requestId":"cfa18a20-3c2c-4806-ac36-9d4e9ba7738c","values":null}}

Here is my method to get a ActiveDirectoryClient:

```
using Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient;
using Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient.Extensions;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory;

private ActiveDirectoryClient CreateGraphClient()
{
        string tenantId = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:TenantId"],
            applicationId = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientId"],
            secret = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientSecret"],
            authority = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AADInstance"] + tenantId,
            resrouce = "https://graph.windows.net",
            token = string.Empty;

        ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(applicationId, secret);
        AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);

        try
        {
            token = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resrouce, credential).Result.AccessToken;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            token = authContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(resrouce, credential.ClientId).Result.AccessToken;
        }

        Uri baseServiceUri = new Uri(resrouce);

        ActiveDirectoryClient activeDirectoryClient = new ActiveDirectoryClient(new Uri(baseServiceUri, tenantId), async () => await Task.FromResult(token));

        return activeDirectoryClient;
}
```

I think the server should refresh the token but it's not happenning. I'm using ADAL 3.x so the 'refresh_token' doesn't exist anymore (I guess).

I know this try/catch is not the way but it was a test.

Any help?

Comment: You're supposed to call `authContext.AcquireTokenAsync`, before each request, that's what calls the cache and if your access token is expired will call into ADAL to renew it. Right now you're returning an `ActiveDirectoryClient` which will have a stale token, forever.

Comment: @evilSnobu I have two methods that need the ActiveDirectoryClient. One to get groups from one user and one to get users from a group, so I created this method to return a ActiveDirectoryClient and not repeat code (ClientCredential, AuthentucationContext, etc).
It's wrong? Do I have to repeat the code?